# using $mdDialog.confirm() closing the parent page

Tags: angularjs

> I have open a template by using **$mdDialog.show()** like this:-

```
 $mdDialog.show({
skipHide: true,
 controller: 'EditController',
templateUrl: 'app/View/Edit.html',
parent: angular.element(document.body),
clickOutsideToClose: false
});
```

> Now I am tring to show the alert before saving the data by using the
>   $mdDialog.confirm() like this:-

```
  var confirm = $mdDialog.confirm()                                                 .parent(angular.element(document.body))
    .content('Are you sure to save the document? ')
    .ok('Save')
    .cancel('Cancel')
$mdDialog.show(confirm).then(function () {}
    ,function () { $mdDialog.hide();
        });
```

> Issue : Closing the opened template after opening the alert.

Answer (score 4):

Multiple dialogues can be opened at the same time:

> Using the `multiple` option for the $mdDialog service allows developers to show multiple dialogs at the same time.

**Example:**

```
// From plain options
$mdDialog.show({
      multiple: true
});

// From a dialog preset
$mdDialog.show(
      $mdDialog
     .confirm()
     .multiple(true)
);
```

Here is the [**Reference**](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDialog) for this.